# How to see node number history in Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

When I see AWS console, the cost of Redshift rose sharply.
The reserved instance is still work and I don't use Redshift spectrum.

I doubted that the compute node was increased.

So that I would like to comfirm node number history.

Are there any way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have concurrency scaling turned on?  This allows Redshift to add extra clusters to the compute capacity to meet increase workload demands.  This does come with extra cost when it occurs.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/concurrency-scaling.html

Comment: Also if you turn on detailed billing reports you can see the exact line items that are increasing you Redshift spend and their description will help you understand their cause.